# ADB not recognizing device after installed Tethering software

Tags: android, macos

I installed some tethering software on my Mac which, apparently, caused ADB to stop recognizing devices. Sure enough the troubleshoot guide on the software's site (http://www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/android_faq.html#adbmacosx) said to unload the driver manually by using the `kextunload` command in the terminal.

I did that, but still my Mac won't recognize any devices....

Anyone have any suggestions? I really need ADB to recognize devices! I can't keep using the emulator!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `kextunload` to stop the EasyTether drivers from loading, I switched my usb cable to a different port on my MacBook and it worked.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to permanently delete EasyTether from your mac so that it wouldn't load back up when you rebooted your mac?

Answer (score 1):

(I guess the statement "If you're developing on Mac OS X, it just works. Skip this step." is not 100% true...)

I can think two options:

- Make sure you have usb debugging still ON on the device
- restart adb  (`adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`)

Comment: lol, true. it all "just worked" after I simply plugged my usb cable into a different port.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with EasyTether Lite.  I had installed EasyTether Lite on my Mac and on my Droid Bionic.

I tried using the kextunload but adb devices still didn't show my device.  I tried various things but ultimately the only thing that worked was to completely uninstall EasyTether Lite from both my Mac and my device.  Here are the steps.

1. Open Finder and navigate to /System/Library/Extensions
2. Drag EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext to the trash
3. Reboot Mac
4. Uninstall EasyTether Lite from device
5. Reboot device